# How to prevent CGAL from generating degenerate tetrahedron in 3D Alpha Shape?

Tags: c++, cgal

I am trying to retrieve the tetrahedrons inside an alpha shape in 3D for some FEM computation. The code I use looks like this:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_cell_base_3.h>


typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                 Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT                                                          FT;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<std::size_t, Kernel>    Vb3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<Kernel, Vb3>                        asVb3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_cell_base_3<Kernel>                               asCb3;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<asVb3,asCb3>                   asTds3;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<Kernel,asTds3, CGAL::Fast_location>  asTriangulation_3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_3<asTriangulation_3>                              Alpha_shape_3;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                                     Point_3;
typedef Kernel::Tetrahedron_3                                               Tetrahedron_3;

void triangulateAlphaShape3D()
{
    ...

    const Alpha_shape_3 as(pointsList.begin(), pointsList.end(),
                           FT(alpha),
                           Alpha_shape_3::GENERAL);

    for(Alpha_shape_3::Finite_cells_iterator fit = as.finite_cells_begin() ;
        fit != as.finite_cells_end() ; ++fit)
    {
        if(as.classify(fit) == Alpha_shape_3::INTERIOR)
        {
            const Alpha_shape_3::Cell_handle cell{fit};

            const std::vector<std::size_t> element{cell->vertex(0)->info(),
                                                   cell->vertex(1)->info(),
                                                   cell->vertex(2)->info(),
                                                   cell->vertex(3)->info()};
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

My point list is composed of point which form a cube in a box. The output of CGAL is (vizualized in gmsh):

[Output of CGAL vizualized in gmsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e47Cz.png)

However it seems there is some kind of crossed/overlapping elements in the figure, and the program throw the following when executed through gdb in debug with a breakpoint at the alpha shape constructor: "Undecidable conversion of CGAL::Uncertain" from the file Uncertain.h:

```cpp
T make_certain() const
  {
    if (is_certain())
      return _i;
    CGAL_PROFILER(std::string("Uncertain_conversion_exception thrown for CGAL::Uncertain< ")
          + typeid(T).name() + " >");
    throw Uncertain_conversion_exception(
                  "Undecidable conversion of CGAL::Uncertain<T>");
  }
```

The call stack is:

```
#0 0xa31c08 libstdc++-6!.cxa_throw() (libstdc++-6.dll:??)
#1 0x62060a4a   CGAL::Uncertain<bool>::make_certain(this=0x22d0ac) (CGAL/Uncertain.h:125)
#2 0x62060ae5   CGAL::Uncertain<bool>::operator bool(this=0x22d0ac) (CGAL/Uncertain.h:133)
#3 0x620240bd   CGAL::coplanar_orientationC3<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >(px=..., py=..., pz=..., qx=..., qy=..., qz=..., rx=..., ry=..., rz=...) (CGAL/predicates/kernel_ftC3.h:209)
#4 0x62056e68   CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Coplanar_orientation_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >::operator() (this=0x22d5af, p=..., q=..., r=...) (CGAL/Cartesian/function_objects.h:3649)
#5 0x620518ea   CGAL::Filtered_predicate<CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Coplanar_orientation_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Mpzf> >, CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Coplanar_orientation_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<CGAL::Cartesian_base_no_ref_count<double, CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Mpzf>, CGAL::NT_converter<double, CGAL::Mpzf> >, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<CGAL::Cartesian_base_no_ref_cou (CGAL/Filtered_predicate.h:167)
#6 0x6205081f   CGAL::Triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_bas (CGAL/Triangulation_3.h:589)
#7 0x62059ec2   CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:1509)
#8 0x6205950e   CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:1545)
#9 0x6205988c   CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:775)
#10 0x620599c9  CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:857)
#11 0x6204e578  CGAL::Triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_bas (CGAL/Triangulation_3.h:1323)
#12 0x6201d924  CGAL::Triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_bas (CGAL/Triangulation_3.h:3696)
#13 0x620254cc  CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:1165)
#14 0x620257bd  CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:1150)
#15 0x62025636  CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_v (CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h:537)
#16 0x62027f9c  CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_3<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CG (CGAL/Triangulation_hierarchy_3.h:279)
#17 0x6202816f  CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_3<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Triangulation_hierarchy_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CG (CGAL/Triangulation_hierarchy_3.h:300)
#18 0x62017b27  CGAL::Alpha_shape_3<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<unsigned long long, CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_3<void> > >, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> >, CGAL::Alpha_shape_cell_base_3<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Default, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false>, CGAL::Boolean_tag<false> >, CGAL::Sequential_tag>, CGAL (CGAL/Alpha_shape_3.h:269)
```

Are they some kind of degenerate tetrahedrons ? How can I prevent CGAL from generating them ?

I currently use CGAL 4.11.

**Update**: I switched to CGAL 5.0.2 and the problem with the throw disappeared. However I still have this strange problem. Test code:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_cell_base_3.h>

#include <gmsh.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel                 Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT                                                          FT;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<std::size_t, Kernel>    Vb3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_vertex_base_3<Kernel, Vb3>                        asVb3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_cell_base_3<Kernel>                               asCb3;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<asVb3,asCb3>                   asTds3;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<Kernel,asTds3, CGAL::Fast_location>  asTriangulation_3;
typedef CGAL::Alpha_shape_3<asTriangulation_3>                              Alpha_shape_3;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                                     Point_3;
typedef Kernel::Tetrahedron_3                                               Tetrahedron_3;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-0.000000001, 0.000000001);
    //std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,0);

    std::vector<std::vector<std::size_t>> elementsList;

    const double alpha = 0.9;

    // We have to construct an intermediate representation for CGAL. We also reset
    // nodes properties.
    std::vector<std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t>> pointsList;

    std::size_t counter = 0;

    /********************************************************************************
                                     Box Nodes
     *******************************************************************************/
    for(double y = 1; y < 10 ; y += 1)
    {
        for(double z = 1; z <= 10 ; z += 1)
        {
            std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t> point = std::make_pair(Point_3(10, y + dist(mt), z + dist(mt)), counter);
            pointsList.push_back(point);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for(double x = 0; x <= 10 ; x += 1)
    {
        for(double z = 1; z <= 10 ; z += 1)
        {
            std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t> point = std::make_pair(Point_3(x+ dist(mt), 0, z+ dist(mt)), counter);
            pointsList.push_back(point);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for(double y = 1; y <= 10 ; y += 1)
    {
        for(double z = 1; z <= 10 ; z += 1)
        {
            std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t> point = std::make_pair(Point_3(0, y+ dist(mt), z+ dist(mt)), counter);
            pointsList.push_back(point);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for(double x = 1; x <= 10 ; x += 1)
    {
        for(double z = 1; z <= 10 ; z += 1)
        {
            std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t> point = std::make_pair(Point_3(x+ dist(mt), 10, z+ dist(mt)), counter);
            pointsList.push_back(point);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    for(double x = 0; x <= 10 ; x += 1)
    {
        for(double y = 0; y <= 10 ; y += 1)
        {
            std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t> point = std::make_pair(Point_3(x+ dist(mt), y+ dist(mt), 0), counter);
            pointsList.push_back(point);
            counter++;
        }
    }


    /********************************************************************************
                                     Cube nodes
     *******************************************************************************/
    for(double x = 1; x <= 5 ; x += 1)
    {
        for(double y = 1; y <= 5 ; y += 1)
        {
            for(double z = 1; z <= 5 ; z += 1)
            {
                std::pair<Point_3, std::size_t> point = std::make_pair(Point_3(x+ dist(mt), y+ dist(mt), z+ dist(mt)), counter);
                pointsList.push_back(point);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    std::random_shuffle(pointsList.begin(), pointsList.end());

    for(std::size_t n = 0; n < pointsList.size() ; ++n)
    {
        pointsList[n].second = n;
    }

    for(std::size_t n = 0 ; n < pointsList.size() ; ++n)
    {
        for(std::size_t n2 = 0 ; n2 < pointsList.size() ; ++n2)
        {
            if(n != n2)
            {
                if(pointsList[n].first == pointsList[n2].first)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Duplicate node found: " << "(" << pointsList[n].first.x() << ", "
                                                                 << pointsList[n].first.y() << ", "
                                                                 << pointsList[n].first.z() << ")";
                    std::cerr << std::endl;
                    std::cerr << "Counter: " << pointsList[n].second << " vs " << pointsList[n2].second << std::endl;
                    throw std::runtime_error("Duplicates nodes!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Number of point: " << pointsList.size() << std::endl;

    const Alpha_shape_3 as(pointsList.begin(), pointsList.end(),
                           FT(alpha),
                           Alpha_shape_3::GENERAL);

    // We check for each triangle which one will be kept (alpha shape), then we
    // perfom operations on the remaining elements
    for(Alpha_shape_3::Finite_cells_iterator fit = as.finite_cells_begin() ;
        fit != as.finite_cells_end() ; ++fit)
    {
        // If true, the elements are fluid elements
        if(as.classify(fit) == Alpha_shape_3::INTERIOR)
        {
            const Alpha_shape_3::Cell_handle cell{fit};

            const std::vector<std::size_t> element{cell->vertex(0)->info(),
                                                   cell->vertex(1)->info(),
                                                   cell->vertex(2)->info(),
                                                   cell->vertex(3)->info()};

            elementsList.push_back(element);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Number of Element: " << elementsList.size() << std::endl;

    gmsh::initialize();
    gmsh::model::add("theModel");
    gmsh::model::setCurrent("theModel");
    gmsh::model::addDiscreteEntity(0, 1);
    gmsh::model::addDiscreteEntity(3, 2);
    gmsh::view::add("Nothing", 1);

    std::vector<std::size_t> nodesTags(pointsList.size());
    std::vector<double> nodesCoord(3*pointsList.size());

    for(std::size_t n = 0 ; n < pointsList.size() ; ++n)
    {
        nodesTags[n] = n + 1;
        nodesCoord[3*n] = pointsList[n].first.x();
        nodesCoord[3*n + 1] = pointsList[n].first.y();
        nodesCoord[3*n + 2] = pointsList[n].first.z();
    }

    gmsh::model::mesh::addNodes(0, 1, nodesTags, nodesCoord);

    std::vector<std::size_t> elementTags(elementsList.size());
    std::vector<std::size_t> nodesTagsPerElement(4*elementsList.size());
    for(std::size_t elm = 0 ; elm < elementsList.size() ; ++elm)
    {
        elementTags[elm] = elm + 1;
        for(std::size_t n = 0 ; n < 4 ; ++n)
            nodesTagsPerElement[4*elm + n] = pointsList[elementsList[elm][n]].second + 1;
    }

    gmsh::model::mesh::addElementsByType(2, 4, elementTags, nodesTagsPerElement); //Tetrahedron 4
    gmsh::model::mesh::addElementsByType(1, 15, nodesTags, nodesTags); //Point

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> dataNothing(pointsList.size());

    for(std::size_t n = 0 ; n < pointsList.size() ; ++n)
    {
        const std::vector<double> nothingVec{0};
        dataNothing[n] = nothingVec;
    }

    gmsh::view::addModelData(1, 0, "theModel", "NodeData", nodesTags, dataNothing, 0, 1);

    gmsh::view::write(1, "mesh.msh", false);

    gmsh::model::remove();

    gmsh::finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

If I slightly perturb the points position (In my program I generate the initial state using gmsh and the node position are not perfectly "whole") those strange element appears, while if the node positions are perfectly integers, the number of element is correct (1017 in this case).

Comment: What compiler and OS are you using? If you are using gcc, did you pass the option `-frounding-math` (needed only if not using cmake)?

Comment: Normally cmake should handle it for me. I am using mingw on windows through MSYS2 (I had to install an older package because cmake does not want to find MSYS2' CGAL 5.0)

Comment: Strange. Do you have the same issue if you remove `CGAL::Fast_location` (to use the default)?

Comment: Yes. I have no issue using a similar code in 2D.

Comment: Could you try to come up with a minimal example we can compile and run so that we can try reproduce the pb and fix it?

Comment: I updated the original post with a test code.

Comment: Since you are not changing alpha, could you try the `Fixed_alpha_shape_3` class instead or set the `ExactAlphaComparisonTag` to `CGAL::Tag_true`. It might be that the unexpected result is due to non-robust alpha comparision.

Comment: Still the same with both.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what issue you are having since you no longer have any exception thrown.

Comment: If you look at the image, it seems there are "overlapping" elements (look at the crossed faces). I would like that each region of space was only occupied by one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I kinda figured out a way to prevent those slivers from appearing. I was generating in gmsh "transfinite" meshes on the boundaries, which means the nodes were postionned like in a perfect square grid. By relaxing that condition, I ended up with a initial set of nodes forming equilateral triangles on the boundary, which did not generate slivers.

I still need to find a way to prevent slivers to appear as the mesh deform, but this has nothing to do with CGAL.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically consists in points being on a regular grid that you then slightly perturb. As a result you end up with what is commonly called slivers (look for "slivers tet mesh" in your favorite search engine). My advice here would be to generate the initial mesh using the regular grid and apply the perturbation on the input (you can easily store the perturbation in your loop since you have ids on vertices).

Comment: The problem is I do not have access to a regular grid. In my "true" code, I load a initial set of point from gmsh. This set of point is potentially not regular, depending on the mesh density and the initial domain. Here, the random perturbation is simply here to represent that, when generating the initial grid of points of a simple test problem (a cube in a box), the initial position are not whole. But for a realistic test case, even without gmsh the position of the nodes will not be whole at all (I am using this mesh for PFEM computation)

Comment: Is not it possible for CGAL to not generate those slivers or to delete them afterwards ?

Comment: The alpha-shape is a subset of the Delaunay triangulation and those slivers are part of the Delaunay Triangulation (nothing specific to CGAL here). Can't you snap your points to a grid then? In theory, I guess the [sliver exuder](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/group__PkgMesh3Functions.html#gabf09a95838226da018a742a631824af9) in the Mesh_3 package could be used but this would mean turning the output of the alpha-shape into a [C3T3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__complex__3__in__triangulation__3.html) but I don't expect it to be straightforward.

Comment: I come back to you some month after our last discussion ^^. Is not there a way to generate a Delaunay triangulation without slivers using CGAL ?

Comment: Again it is not specific to CGAL, those slivers are part of the Delaunay triangulation. The Delaunay triangulation is unique if you don't have co-spherical points.

Comment: I do not understand how those flat tetrahedra are part of the triangulation if when I remove them all the points are still inside one triangle each. They seem useless.